# I need help with android ROWSPAN and LIStACTIVITY within a Cell of Table Layout

Tags: android, html-table

I need to span multiple rows at the left most column for a particular layout. in 1 column i want text to be written verticdally and it spans atleast 4 to 5 rows with the same text.

Kindly suggest relevant sml or java code.
Nermeen Nasim

Answer (score 1):

There is no "rowspan" concept with `TableLayout`. You will need to design your UI using other containers in addition to, or perhaps instead of, `TableLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use GridLayout instead, you can tell the views the properties: android:layout_rowSpan and android:layout_columnSpan. 
Worked for me.