# can grid view have column spanning one or more rows

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout

Is it possible to have a grid view with 2 columns and  3 rows with a condition
cell1 (row1,col1) spans to row2,col2 as well. ie there is no cell (row2,col1) and the cell (row1,col1) occupy its space as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GridView` does not support spanning. A `TableLayout` however does. See this older topic: [Android - GridView : Specify Column Span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272742/android-gridview-specify-column-span)

Comment: Actully I  realised what i was looking for is row span, not col span though worded wrongly. Does tablelayout support row spanning?

Comment: It does not support any kind of spanning. It just supports showing views in a Grid.

Comment: I saw tablelayout supporting column spanning . My question was does TABLELAYOUT support row spanning . thanks

Comment: Sorry, little late here :D No, there seams to be no support for that in `TableLayout`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017657/i-need-help-with-android-rowspan-and-listactivity-within-a-cell-of-table-layout). You'll need to use something else.

Comment: Ok . Thanks a lot. I saw the same answer on search,  wanted this to be confirmed.